# How to change empty value of EmberJS relationship

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, relationship

I have two models with relationship, in the current system an empty relationship is represented not by a `null` like in EmberJS but by an empty `""` string.

Is there a way to use empty string instead of null?

Comment: Have you tried overwriting your adapter?

Comment: I don't use any adapter. I only use `store.pushPayload`.

Comment: Okay, then you might want to overwrite your serializer http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#toc_across-the-board-normalization

Comment: Oh yeah ok this should be the trick

Comment: @Remi I suggest posting it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using pushPayload, you might want to overwrite your serializer, see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#toc_across-the-board-normalization)

Comment: This was quite easy thanks: `App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
 extractRelationship: function (relationshipModelName, relationshipHash) {
  if (relationshipHash === '') {
   return null;
  } else {
   return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
 }
});`